# Create Map on Iphone

Tags: iphone

I am wondering how to create a click able map on Iphone similar to this one http://www.flashimap.com/clickable-map/UNITED_STATES/

I need to create my own map image with my own coloring schema.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking out the [MapKit API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html). It uses Google Maps and is the one that's used internally by the iPhone Maps application. It is available for any app to use.

Comment: I actually need to create my own map image with my own coloring schema.

Comment: Then the short answer is going to be "a lot of drawing." Why is MapKit's color scheme unacceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If the MapKit API isn't suitable, take a look at the [route me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) API paired with a custom map tile provider such as [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the on the website you mentioned above a link to their online mapping software at http://www.imapbuilder.net/, which seems to support HTML5 and Google map, and both can work on iPhone.